# spring security StackOverflow Error

Tags: security, spring-boot, stack-overflow

I am implementing security in spring boot application and receiving StackOverflow exception.
i have a User pojo and repository to save user in DB which is working fine.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    ....
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService); }
```

and

```java
public class User {

    private String password;

    public User(User user) {
        this.password = user.password;
        ...
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
```

expecting User's getPassword() to get called below but not happening -

```java
public class MyUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails{
    ........
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return getPassword();
}
```

Implementation of UserDetailsService  -

```java
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    if (user == null)
         throw new UsernameNotFoundException("no " + email);
    return new MyUserDetails(user);
}
```

I have inserted one user/password in DB by calling userRepository.save(user).
When i try to pass invalid user/password , it is returning invalid user message correctly.
But when i try with user/password stored in DB i get following exception -

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at com.xyz.MyUserDetails.getPassword(MyUserDetails.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at `MyUserDetails.getPassword()` method, you can see that it will call itself... infinitely...

```
public class MyUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails{
    ........
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return getPassword(); // <= infinite recursion here
}
```

Was there perhaps a variable with a similar name that you wanted to return, or maybe call a different method (from the super class.. or not..)?

Comment: updated my post with User Class that has getPassword method.

Comment: @chappalprasad  Why do you overwrite  the `getPassword()` method in `MyUserDetails`? Since it's defined as public in the `User` class, it can be simply accessed without requiring any particular handling.

Comment: yeah, i made some progress. by calling super.getPassword() but you are right , can just remove override annotation. In Both cases now i get this error - Reason: No enum constant com.xyz.resource.Role.ROLE_USER<BR> . I am using Enum Role as part of USER with two Values - USER,ADMIN.

Comment: @chappalprasad From the looks of it, `com.xyz.resource.Role.ROLE_USER` is what it expects to find instead of `com.xyz.resource.Role.USER`...

Comment: yes after making enums as ROLE_USER it works fine. However Override doesn't work and goes in stack overflow but that is fine with calling parents method. I am not sure if ROLE_USER is something spring checks internally or i can go with whatever roles i want. Thnx for your hints , helped me solve the problem.

Comment: @chappalprasad no problem, glad I could help. If an answer helped you fix the problem, you can accept it by clicking on the *check* symbol (the v) in front of it. Indeed ROLE_USER is something checked by Spring. I played a while ago with Spring Security and I remember running into it and I just went along with it. Probably it can be configured somehow but I haven't gotten to deep in the details... As for overriding the method, it should work as long as you call `super.getPassword()` but unless you need to do some additional processing I don't see a reason. Cheers